# UDF for User name / time stamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm currently using the below code to stamp an Excel report.

```
Public Function ApplySignOff(iSignatureOffset, sGroup As Integer)
Dim sDisplayName As String
Dim SingleSignOffCheck As String


sDisplayName = GetDisplayName(Environ("USERNAME"))
SingleSignOffCheck = Environ("USERDOMAIN") & "\" & Environ("USERNAME")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Unprtsht
    ActiveCell.Value = sDisplayName & " (" & SingleSignOffCheck & "  " & Now & ")"

    Prtsht

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

I want to covert the code into a UDF.  Basically `=UDFNAME(A1)`.  So if `A1` is not blank then apply the stamp above.  I have tried multiple different approaches, but I think I'm missing a step.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: A UDF cant change cell contents (atleast not without jumping through hoops)

Comment: Thanks Siphor for your feedback.  I think I maynot have explained myself correctly.  I don't want ot change the cell content.  If I put the UDF in a range (e.g. A2) - I want it to look at a variable range (e.g. A1).  So UDF would be if A1 <> blank apply the stamps in my code.  Is it possible to change the cell content using a condition in another cell?  Thanks again for support - Ciaran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ActiveCell.Value to the name of the function

```
ActiveCell.Value = sDisplayName & " (" & SingleSignOffCheck & "  " & Now & ")"
```

to

```
ApplySignOff = sDisplayName & " (" & SingleSignOffCheck & "  " & Now & ")"
```

and modify function definition to

```
Public Function ApplySignOff(iSignatureOffset, sGroup As Integer) as String
```

then if it compiles clean you can use =ApplySignOff() in your worksheet

Comment: Thsnk you - Once I added a set range to look at as a condition your suggesion worked - Thank you for the support.  Ciaran.